# Obtener todos los productos de una categoría Mercadolibre

Tags: python, api, requests

estoy queriendo obtener todos los productos de la categoria "Indumentaria", para esto hago el siguiente request:

https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/MLA/search?category=MLA1430&search_type=scan&offset=4001

Variando el numero de offset, pero tengo el problema que obtengo:

```
{

"message": "the requested offset is higher than the allowed for public users. Maximum allowed is 1000",

"error": "forbidden",

"status": 403,

"cause": []

}
```

Incluyo dentro de los headers el token, el cual es correcto porque si hago un request a:

https://api.mercadolibre.com/users/me

Obtengo los datos de la cuenta.

Ya estoy poniendo search_type=scan y no me funciona, si no pongo el numero de offset obtengo:

```
"site_id": "MLA",

"country_default_time_zone": "GMT-03:00",

"paging": {

"total": 2712527,

"primary_results": 1000,

"offset": 0,

"limit": 50

},

"results": [
```

Donde tampoco está el parametro scroll_id como para desplazarme dentro de la busqueda.

Hay alguna solucion? Gracias.

Comment: La solución más corta es leer. Cambia el parámetro `offset` de 4001 a 1000 o menos. He probado eso ahorita mismo, y la API funciona.

Comment: Si, eso lo he probado, pero si quiero obtener todos los productos de la categoría, tengo que ir variando este offset, pero cuando paso este numero ya no puedo. Esto indicaría que no se pueden obtener TODOS los productos de una categoría?

Comment: Si estás hablando de obtener absolutamente todos los productos de una categoría, eso no es posible. Hay varias razones, la principal es que puede que sean millones de registros, y eso va a requerir que el servidor trabaje demasiado y consuma demasiados recursos para servir el contenido, otra razón es que el contenido será demasiado pesado, y podría incurrir en falta de memoria y rendimiento deficiente para el cliente y el servidor, es por esta razón que algunos sitios web no cargan de golpe todo el contenido si es masivo, sino que lo cargan progresivamente a medida que el usuario desliza.

Comment: Otra razón es el tiempo de ejecución. Extraer tantos registros en un solo impacto hará que la base de datos funcione de manera deficiente, el servidor se sature y el tiempo de ejecución se vaya a las nubes. Procesar tanta información consume tiempo, e incluso paralelizando el proceso, el tiempo sería masivo. Por estas razones no es posible obtener tantos datos en un solo impacto.

Comment: Probablemente mercado libre NO hace una consulta de todas las categorías para mostrar sus paginas, si no que hace una consulta a la base de datos con solamente la info necesaria para mostrar la pagina. Si estás haciendo una interfáz grafica con paginas, es buena practica hacer de este modo. Es decir, si necesitas mostrar la pagina 3 y cada pagina tiene 100 items, consulta con un offset de 200 y un limite de 100.

Comment: Gracias a ambos! Por el momento lo solucione buscando solo productos de algunos vendedores, entonces hago el request para obtener los productos vendidos por ciertos vendedores. Pensaba ir obteniendo productos variando el offset, pero cuando el offset es mayor a 4000 lo rechaza